# iOS UIBarButtonItems for navigation and sharing

Tags: icons, ios

I am creating app and I need in detail page for item add some bar image buttons to rightBarButtonItems of navigation bar. I know that there are [several predefined styles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007519-CH3-SW2) but I am not sure which images to use for share button and for button which runs navigation. How they should look like that user immediately knows purpose. For which use there is action style in predefined styles? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Share** icon is:

[image]

As defined here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW33

Answer (score 1):

There are icons that have been so widely adopted now that they have become useful for situations like this because everyone knows what they mean; though you could just say "Share" in the titlebar and that would to the trick.

Default Android share button icon: [image]

Default iOS 7 share button icon: [image]

As for your other question about navigation you would want a chevron arrow pointing to the left on the left side of your titlebar like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with Android icon and I was almost sure that it wouldn't be right one for iOS. But as navigation icon I mean icon that after tap would run 3rd party applications (or Apple app) which navigate user to exact place.

Answer (score 1):

If by "running the navigation" you mean showing other sections of the app/site vs going backwards or forwards (the chevron left or right), then you can use what many applications tend to use which is the three horizontal stacked lines or what some refer to as the "hamburger" button.  The "hamburger" button has become synonymous with showing/hiding the navigation options/sections of the app or page.  When the user clicks it, a dropdown appears or the screen slides out to reveal different options.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I give you +1 because your answer is describing but as I wrote in another comment. By navigation I mean icon which after clicked run app which user navigates to the place. I am sorry if it's another word in english. Do you know icon like that?